# How to retrive large data with resquest.get

Tags: python, request

I want to retrive data from a server. But the dataset is too large, using request.get takes too much time. It's about 200000 json entites. I am wondering, is there any way to reduce the time? My code is like below:

```
data = json.loads(requests.get(url).text["value"])
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please help us by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)